# Как ограничить вывод числа 0-999 и всего тремя числами после запятой в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

У меня есть input и мне нужно тобы он мог выводить только числа 1-999, а если это не целое число то выводилось только три числа после запятой.Input должен обязательно быть type='number'  поэтому я не могу использовать maxLength='3. Я не могу использовать max='999' в таком случае оно работает не совсем так как мне нужно. Сейчас я решил это с помощью кода ниже (если число больше 999, я делю его на 10 и оставляю целую часть). Но в этом случае я все еще могу написать число, например, 0,1234567. Может быть, есть способ сделать так, чтобы я мог написать просто число от 0 до 999, и если это не целое я могу написать только три числа после запятой, например 0,123

```
     <input
        type='number'
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          let val = Number(e.target.value);
          onChange(val > 999 ? Math.trunc(val / 10) : val);
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то как-то так.

```
function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
}

return (
   <input
        type='number'
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          let val = Number(e.target.value);
          onChange(val > 999 ? value : isInt(val) ? val : val.toFixed(3));
        }}
   />
)
```